# Spring MVC resource versioning adding the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to get the new resource versioning from 4.1 working. From

http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

I can't seem to register the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter correctly.  How do you do that so it picks up urls in jsp?
I'm using javaconfig and in my extended WebMvcConfigurerAdapter --> addResourceHandlers method I have

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(
                    new VersionResourceResolver()
                            .addFixedVersionStrategy("1.1.0", "/**/*.js")
                            .addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
```

This seems to work as I can get the changes in a controller

```
@Autowired
private ResourceUrlProvider resourceUrlProvider;


@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePub() {

    logger.debug("js =  '{}'", this.resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath("/static/test.js"));
    logger.debug("css =  '{}'", this.resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath("/static/test.css"));

    return "test";
}
```

Will output

```
DEBUG TestController - js =  '/static/1.1.0/test.js'
DEBUG TestController - css = '/static/styles/test-4c517674c05348b2aa87420e7adc420b.css'
```

Initially urls in jsp's are ignored so I added

```
container.addFilter("resourceUrlEncodingFilter",  ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(
            null, true, "/*");
```

To my implementation of WebApplicationInitializer

This gives the exception below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine lookup path: /test/static/test.js
```

So at least I know the filter is being called it just hasn't picked up my handlers
I tried adding a resource handler for /test/static/** as well but that didn't help.
Changing the isMatchAfter to false stops the exception but the filter doesn't seem to be called.

The jsp is question is very simple

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<c:url value='/static/test.js'/>
```

So I guess that's not how to set up the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter, how should it be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12279

You need to add

```
@Override
public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = (SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) super.resourceHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setInterceptors(this.getInterceptors());
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

And extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport instead of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

There are other problems

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12281

And the securityFilter causes it problems but the above should get the basics working

Update: release of 4.1.2 solves these problems