# ResourceUrlEncodingFilter in Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE with springSecurityFilterChain enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

im trying to implement resource versioning to make my static files (js and css) dynamically versioned by spring's VersionResourceResolver according to [Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources)
i have my xml configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/">
    <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true" auto-registration="true">
        <mvc:resolvers>
            <mvc:version-resolver>
                <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
            </mvc:version-resolver>
        </mvc:resolvers>
    </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/">
    <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true" auto-registration="true">
        <mvc:resolvers>
            <mvc:version-resolver>
                <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
            </mvc:version-resolver>
        </mvc:resolvers>
    </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
```

that works quite well when i add the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter in my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>addMappingForUrlPatterns</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

the only thing is that it doesn't work when the springSecurityFilterChain is present on the web.xml, if i comment the line of springSecurityFilterChain the filter works perfectly, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276342/spring-mvc-resource-versioning-adding-the-resourceurlencodingfilter)
post appears to be a bug solved on the 4.1.2 version, as specified [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12332)

that url's of static files are just completely ignored, the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter only call it's encodeURL() method when security its not enabled, any ideas of how to solve it? i assumed that the solution for that bug was added to the 4.1.5.RELEASE version.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your filter (ResourceUrlEncodingFilter) is only getting called when security is not enabled makes me believe that Spring Security is intercepting the calls to your static resources (and not letting them pass through to the filter). Please verify that your Spring Security configuration lets calls to static resources through.

Assuming that your 'css' and 'js' folders are under src/main/resources, you could do something like this:

(JavaConfig)

```
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
    ...

}
```

(XML configuration)

```
...

<http security="none" pattern="/resources/**"/>

...
```

Comment: sorry for the late comment, and thank you for your response, i use spring security 3.0.2, my url's interception in my security config is :
<security:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" filters="none" />

  <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" filters="none"/>

  <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" filters="none"/>

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
Looks like it's related to the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper that spring security uses as a wrapper for HttpServletRequest. It replaces some critical methods implementation required for ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.

For now I used an ugly hack by creating two filters:

First does this (should be the first in filter chain):

```
    static final String INITIAL_REQUEST_ATTR = "INITIAL_REQUEST";

     @Override
     protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.setAttribute(INITIAL_REQUEST_ATTR, request);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

And the second is basically hacked copy of ResourceUrlEncodingFilter
mapped to my dispatcher servlet (you replace standard with it)

```
public class ResourceUrlEncodingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest) || !(response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
        throw new ServletException("ResourceUrlEncodingFilter just supports HTTP requests");
    }

    HttpServletRequest initialRequest =
            (HttpServletRequest) request.getAttribute(InitialRequestStoreFilter.INITIAL_REQUEST_ATTR);

    if (initialRequest == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Initial request is not stored");
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request,
            new ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper(initialRequest, (HttpServletResponse) response));
}

private static class ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private final HttpServletRequest initialRequest;

    /* Cache the index and prefix of the path within the DispatcherServlet mapping */
    private Integer indexLookupPath;

    private String prefixLookupPath;

    ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper(HttpServletRequest initialRequest, HttpServletResponse wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
        this.initialRequest = initialRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public String encodeURL(String url) {
        ResourceUrlProvider resourceUrlProvider = getResourceUrlProvider();
        if (resourceUrlProvider == null) {
            log.debug("Request attribute exposing ResourceUrlProvider not found");
            return super.encodeURL(url);
        }

        initLookupPath(resourceUrlProvider);
        if (url.startsWith(this.prefixLookupPath)) {
            int suffixIndex = getQueryParamsIndex(url);
            String suffix = url.substring(suffixIndex);
            String lookupPath = url.substring(this.indexLookupPath, suffixIndex);
            lookupPath = resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath(lookupPath);
            if (lookupPath != null) {
                return super.encodeURL(this.prefixLookupPath + lookupPath + suffix);
            }
        }

        return super.encodeURL(url);
    }

    private ResourceUrlProvider getResourceUrlProvider() {
        return (ResourceUrlProvider) this.initialRequest.getAttribute(
                ResourceUrlProviderExposingInterceptor.RESOURCE_URL_PROVIDER_ATTR);
    }

    private void initLookupPath(ResourceUrlProvider urlProvider) {
        if (this.indexLookupPath == null) {
            UrlPathHelper pathHelper = urlProvider.getUrlPathHelper();
            String requestUri = pathHelper.getRequestUri(this.initialRequest);
            String lookupPath = pathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(this.initialRequest);
            this.indexLookupPath = requestUri.lastIndexOf(lookupPath);
            this.prefixLookupPath = requestUri.substring(0, this.indexLookupPath);

            if ("/".equals(lookupPath) && !"/".equals(requestUri)) {
                String contextPath = pathHelper.getContextPath(this.initialRequest);
                if (requestUri.equals(contextPath)) {
                    this.indexLookupPath = requestUri.length();
                    this.prefixLookupPath = requestUri;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int getQueryParamsIndex(String url) {
        int index = url.indexOf("?");
        return (index > 0 ? index : url.length());
    }
}
```

}

This works but it's not a good solution on my opinion.
So hopefully it will be fixed or somebody will provide a better solution

Comment: any better solutions found yet? I'm currently facing the same problems.